# asp.net sitemap - how to spoof page in breadcrumb when it's not in the sitemap (on purpose!)

Tags: asp.net, sitemap, breadcrumbs

I'm not experienced with sitemaps - only just started looking into them.  I have an app where the user can choose to do a short quiz/question and answer session. As there are 10 sub-pages in the quiz (for argument's sake called q1.aspx, q2.aspx, etc.) and I DON'T want the user to be able to jump in at, say, q5.aspx, I'm not defining those individual question pages in the sitemap file.

However this means, I think, (from limited testing, it may be my error) that there is no breadcrumb trail available on the individual question page (as there is no matching entry for home/survey/quiz/q1.aspx in the sitemap) when I want there to be something like:

home > survey > quiz

where "quiz" at the end of the breadcrumb trail is a starter page (quiz.aspx for example) that has a link something like "start our quiz" and links  to q1.aspx.

The idea is that all of the q1.aspx to q10.aspx pages have that exact breadcrumb trail whereby the user can simply click on "quiz" to go back to the first page again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sitemap, make your q1.aspx, etc pages children of quiz.aspx.

One way you always have Quiz showing in the breadcrumb is have a method called on those (q1-q10) pages that makes the CurrentNode the parent of the CurrentNode.

Comment: OK, I'll set up that structure and see if it works. Any examples of "a method called ... that makes the CurrentNode the parent of the CurrentNode" please?